# How set the item in ContextActions Xamarin MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

How set the item in ContextActions. In my example I want to set default car.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                             <MenuItem Text="Ustaw domyslny" Command="{Binding DefultCarCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding RegistrationNumber}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Brand}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

In ViewModel I use DelegateCommand

```
public DelegateCommand DefultCarCommand { get; private set; }
```

Now it does not work and I do not know why

Comment: What doesn't work? Is you command not triggered? Does you app crash? Something else?

Comment: Binding doesn't work. I can't run DefultCarCommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note BindingContext of MenuItem is the Single Model that you bind in ItemSource of ListView not the whole ViewModel. You need to use reference binding to bind to ViewModel properties like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                <MenuItem Text="Ustaw domyslny" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DefultCarCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=MyListView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding RegistrationNumber}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Brand}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```